# Intelij IDEA - Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm using java **7** to compile my class files using **maven** **`/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java`**, but still i'm getting below errors. What might i be doing wrong ?

```
    Compilation failure:
    error: generics are not supported in -source 1.3
    error: annotations are not supported in -source 1.3
```

Answer (score 1):

IntelliJ preference > Java > Compiler > Set language level to `1.7`

Project > properties > Project language level > Set language level to `1.7`

Comment: There is no preference in menu bar of my IDE :( @jigar

Comment: I don't know what is the menu in windows, search something for tools > preference intuitively

Answer (score 0):

You have change your pom file:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    [...]
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```